# .click get a piece of json to appear inside an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a get json function that makes items appear on my page, there is a button with json included inside of it that when is clicked I want the item to appear inside an alert (its called cart) - its going to be a simple shopping cart that is hidden on page ready/load. So when the user clicks this button parts of my json file appear inside of the alert, like a shopping cart, If there can be a total to calculate the price this would be good but is not necessary.

So this is my script to get the json and display it on my page :

```
 $.getJSON('iproducts.json',function(products){


var output = "";
$.each(products.appleitems, function(i, product) { 

    output += 
        "<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3\"><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-footer'><h4 class='text-center'>"  
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id 
        + "</h4></div>" + "<img src ='" + products.appleitems[i].Imgpath + "'  style='width:100%;height:250px; display: block;' id='appleinfo_" 
        + products.appleitems[i].Product_id + 
        "' /><p class='lead text-justify'>" + products.appleitems[i].Information
        + "</p><div class='panel-footer'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id='btncart'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button></div></div></div>";
    });

$("#container").html(output);
});
```

as you will notice this is the button I am talking about:

```
<div class='panel-footer'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' id='btncart'>&pound;" + products.appleitems[i].Price+"</button></div>
```

the price is displayed inside of the button.

This is a snip (one of the products, there are about 12 products in total) from my json file:

```
{
"appleitems":[
  {
     "Product_id":"Iphone5",
     "Information":"Iphone 5 64GB",
     "Imgpath":"image/iphone5.jpg",
     "Price":"200.00"
  }
  ]
  }
```

This is the alert I want the name and price to display in when the button is clicked:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" id="cart"></div>
```

Here is a bit of a clue from a previous script I worked on, when the user entered their name/ login details (from the json) and they matched their name, picture and details would appear in the welcome alert, I also had a hide button inside this alert that then hid the welcome alert and this is how I got it to work ( could be quite similar to this only .show():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();
$("#invalid").hide();  
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){

    $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
        var id = $('#userName').val();
        var name = $('#userName2').val();
        var valid = false;


$('#loginalert').html('<img src="' + jd.user[i].imgpath + '"><br><p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p><button type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Hide</button>');      
          //show the alert after loading the information  
                $("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000)
                $('#invalid').hide();
                $('#btnhide').on('click', function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#loginalert').hide();
                });

            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            $('#invalid').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#loginalert').hide();
```

Kind Regards

Comment: kindly reformat your question as it's very hard to read at this moment.Also check my ans.

Answer (score 0):

So on button click you want to update the alert div with it's price.

Here is a code block explaining things you need.

According to this html

[image]

```
$('.btn-block').click(function(e){
      //alert($(this).attr("value")); //get value of button
      $("#cart").empty();  //clear div every time on click
      $("#cart").html($(this).attr("value")); //this will update div with value of button.
      var product_information = $(this).closest("div").prev("p").html();//This will get you product info 
});
```

I have added some explanation as comment.This are self explanatory.

### **Important**

> I notice you assign hardcore id in each loop in button which is not correct.You should always assign dynamic id as id cannot be same.